# Find solutions to an equation within two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

If you are given two arrays A & B, each with n positive numbers and the equation:

```
x^8 = y^6 + x^2y^2 + 10
```

Design an algorithm that runs in nlog(n) time that finds an x in A and a y in B such that the previous equation holds.

First thing to do, is sort both arrays as we want to use binary search later, but the problem is the term

```
x^2y^2
```

which can't be separated on different sides of the equation? Or am I going down the wrong path here?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to notice is that both x and y have even power. That means, when you are sorting you should sort by absolute value (which is still nlogn).

Then, go through each element of array1 and perform a binary search on array 2. You should be able to perform binary search because the function is monotonically increasing. This step is nlogn.

I can elaborate more, if you did not understand my answer.

Let me know :)

Comment: Even powers don't affect the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm. You can ignore the fact that they're even.

Comment: Originally I thought the arrays can have negative numbers, in that case even power is important to make my suggestion work.

Comment: say there is a equation you want to verify x^2=4 and you have [-2,-1,0,1,3] you cannot perform a binary search unless you sort the array like this [0,1,-1,-2,3]. But if the equation is like x^3=-8 then you can perform the binary search with the original array. That's how power matters. The function needs to be monotonic. Hope it makes sense.